# Running number on Oracle UNION

Tags: oracle, union, rownum

What I need is a union query with running number as one of column selected. 
I did try including ROWNUM as part of the query but it gets duplicated over each query. ROWNUM is being reset.

What is the best way to achieve this?

edit:Oracle 9i.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT COL1,
       COL2,
       COL4,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SORT_COLUMN ) "ROW_NUMBER"
FROM   (
     SELECT COL1,
            COL2,
            COL4,
            SORT_COLUMN
     FROM TABLE_A
     UNION ALL
     SELECT COL1,
            COL2,
            COL4,
            SORT_COLUMN
     FROM TABLE_B
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

Try putting your query in a subquery:

```
select rownum seq, t.*
from (<your_query>) t
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/9804)